# Document contain sub document of array of objects, if sub document empty it doesn't return parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is the structure of parent document, I am trying to fetch the parent document along the child with populated values, but when the child document history array is empty, it return empty array as a result

```
{
  
    "resort" : ObjectId("5d52cd888bb76e30d8ef53f3"),
    "bookingAgent" : ObjectId("5f196af7117f7306a64bca05"),
    "leadId" : ObjectId("5fc39fe5a270851e6b5d7e78"),
    "contactAttempt" : ObjectId("604149ea7578a7001327b4ee"),
    "household" : ObjectId("5fc3a3f4a270851e6b7b118c"),
    "finalDisposition" : "No Show",
    "history" : []
}
```

Inside this parent document, history which is array of object has the  following schema

```
    history: [{
        tourDate: {
            type: Date,
            index: true
        },
        departureDate: Date,
        disposition: String,
        confirmationDispostion: String,
        confirmationDate: Date,
        dispositionReason: String,
        bookingImage: String,
        voucher: String,
        bookingAgent: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          refPath: 'staffs'
       },
      resort: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       refPath: 'Resort'
      }
    }]
```

I am trying to query

```
  BookingHistory.aggregate([
      { $match: { household: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "staffs",
          localField: "bookingAgent",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "bookingAgent"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "resorts",
          localField: "resort",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "resort"
        }
      },
      { $unwind: "$history"  },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "resorts",
          localField: "history.resort",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "history.resort"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "staffs",
          localField: "history.bookingAgent",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "history.bookingAgent"
        }
      },
      {$unwind: '$bookingAgent'},
      {$unwind: '$history.bookingAgent'},
      {$unwind: '$history.resort'},
      {$unwind: '$resort'},
      { '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'history': { '$push': '$history' },
        'parent': { '$first': '$$ROOT' },
      }}
    ]);
```

But if subdocument history is empty it return empty array as a result

Comment: @D.SM updated. Can you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

So I have to modify the query to this, `$unwind` has `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`
property

which has the following behaviour
Optional.

- If true, if the path is null, missing, or an empty array, $unwind outputs the document.
- If false, if path is null, missing, or an empty array, $unwind does not output a document.

```
[
      { $match: { household: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "staffs",
          localField: "bookingAgent",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "bookingAgent"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "resorts",
          localField: "resort",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "resort"
        }
      },
      { 
        $unwind: {
          path: "$history",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "resorts",
          localField: "history.resort",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "history.resort"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: { 
          from: "staffs",
          localField: "history.bookingAgent",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "history.bookingAgent"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$bookingAgent',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$history.bookingAgent',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      {  
        $unwind: {
          path: '$history.resort',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        },
      },
      { 
        $unwind: {
          path: '$resort',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      },
      { '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'history': { '$push': '$history' },
        'parent': { '$first': '$$ROOT' },
      }}
    ];
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/